# Android: onLocationChanged never called (Permissions Work)

Tags: java, android, location

A few days ago, the locationservice worked perfectly. Now, the service will still start, but i no longer receive updates from my LocationListener. "OnLocationChanged" is just never called.

This is the code from the service:

```
public class LocationUpdateService extends Service {

private LocationListener locationListener;
private LocationManager locationManager;
private LatLng Location = new LatLng(0,0);
private String best;

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(){
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Looper.prepare();
            Log.i("LocationService", "Called 'onCreate'");

            locationListener = new LocationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                    Intent i = new Intent("location_update");
                    Location = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                    i.putExtra("Longitude", Location.longitude);
                    i.putExtra("Latitude", Location.latitude);
                    sendBroadcast(i);
                    Log.i("LocationService", location.getLongitude() + ", " + location.getLatitude());
                }
                @Override
                public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
                    Log.i("LocationService", "Status Changed");
                }
                @Override
                public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                    Log.i("LocationService", "Provided is Enabled");
                }
                @Override
                public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                    Log.i("LocationService", "Provider is Disabled");
                    Intent i = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            };

            locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            Criteria crit = new Criteria();
            crit.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
            best = locationManager.getBestProvider(crit, false);
            //noinspection MissingPermission
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(best, 10000, 0, locationListener);
        }
    });
    t.start();
}
@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    if(locationManager != null){
        locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
    }
}
}
```

I have all the necessary permissions included in the manifest. I don't receive any update messages in the console, but i do receive the log message that the service has at least started.

Edit: this is how i request the runtime permissions:

```
    private void StartLocationService() {
    Intent LocationService = new Intent(this, LocationUpdateService.class);
    startService(LocationService);
}

private boolean runtime_permissions(){
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 && (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)){
        requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},100);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == 100){
        if ( grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            StartLocationService();
        }
        else {
            runtime_permissions();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I ended up rewriting the class using FusedLocationProvider, and it worked, though it obviously didn't solve my question.

Answer (score 0):

Are you targeting Android 6.0 or above?

If so, adding the permissions to the manifest isn't enough, you need to request Runtime Permissions as well. Checkout https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Maybe it worked before because you were running on a previous version of Android?

Also, I don't think you need to run that on a background thread. Try calling all that on the main thread and see what happens. I have a feeling you shouldn't call startActivity() on a thread other than the UI Thread, but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work.
I request runtime Permissions already, and It didn't work when on the main thread before (i actually tried running it as a background process in the hopes it would solve the issue).

Comment: That's odd. Are you running it on an emulator? I've had trouble getting location changes on emulators before. For some reason the "requestLocationUpdates" doesn't always work on emulators for me and the same code works fine on real devices.